# CSS 2 Div Layout float

Tags: css, layout, html, css-float

kind of embarrassing to ask but I have been toying with it for the past 1 hour at least and cannot get it correctly.

Need 2 div layout. 
Div 1 floated left with a fixed width of 75px
Div 2 floated right with a fixed width of 900px

Now the problem: the margin between div1-div2 and div2-right outer edge needs to be equal.

Comment: what do you mean by outer edge? is there any other wrapper outside? generally, @afshin 's solution is what you need i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting "div 2" in a container that isn't floated. Then remove "div 2"'s float and instead use `display:inline-block`. Add `text-align:center` to the new container of "div 2".

Comment: Thank you. I can't vote up or accept answer because I'm a first timer here but this is the answer if anyone else is looking.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="div1"></div>
<div class="container">
 <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.div1{
 float:left;
 width:75px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:red;
}
.container{
 padding-left:75px;
}
.div2{
 margin:auto;
 width:500px;
 background-color:blue;
 height:100px;
}​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/HK2Nb/)